# Link to populate form data from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form that I need to load data in when the user selects a title from a list. When I save a record, I query the database and put the title of the record in a list, with an Edit and Delete link. I'm having difficulty adding an "a href" to the Edit button, and getting the record data to load in the form.

Here's the code for the query:

```
<div class="content">
<ul class="nav">

<div><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>

<div class="container">
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'my_table' ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$title=$row['title'];
?>

<div class="show">
<Table width="300" Border="0">
<TR><TD width="260"><?php echo $title; ?></TD>

<TD width="20"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">EDIT</a></TD>

<TD width="20"><a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">DELETE</a>
</TD></TR>
</Table>
</div>

<?php
}
?> 
</div>
```

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="process.php" method="post">
<div>

<?php
include"connect-db.php";

$sql="SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<? echo $rows['title']; ?>">
<textarea name="chords" id="chords" rows="1" cols="16"><? echo $rows['chords']; ?></textarea>
<textarea name="lyrics" id="lyrics" rows="4" cols="16"><? echo $rows['lyrics']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Should 'process.php' contain only 1 result from the database, based on the ID?

Comment: I will echo Reinder's comment. What is happening and what do you expect to happen.

Comment: When I submit a record to the database I add the record title to a list on the Web page. I want the user to be able to either click on the title or an edit button and have the form populate for that record. Insert works, and the title listing works. I'm having trouble selecting the title and loading the data back into the form for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If 'process.php' should show the results of 1 record from the database, you need to change the href of the link and pass the ID to process.php as a GET parameter in the URL. In that page, you need to query using that ID parameter.

change links to:

```
<a href="?action=edit&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">EDIT</a>
...
<a href="?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">DELETE</a>
```

In process.php, you need to add some if/else statements:

```
if(isset($_GET["action"]) && isset($_GET["id"]) && is_numeric($_GET["id"])) {
    include"connect-db.php";

    $sql="SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = " . $_GET["id"];
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($_GET["action"] == "edit") {
        // output editing form
    }

    else if($_GET["action"] == "delete") {
        // delete
    }
}
```

You could also use different pages for editing and deleting, change your link accordingly if that's what you want. You might want to have a confirmation section before deleting too...

Please note that passing data like this in the URL makes it very vulnerable to hacking. One could easily change the ID or the action.

Also, you need to migrate your code to use PHP's mysqli function instead of mysql. The mysql ones are deprecated...

Comment: I probably need to rethink the structure. The process file is for inserts into the DB. I have a separate delete file, but I haven't addressed updates yet since I need to get the data back in the form first. It seems I should use process.php for both insert and update. I'm actually not using process.php for the Edit and Delete links to query for data. That code is in my Edit page. The only time I call process.php is when I save a file, or update. As I said, I need to think about the best way to do this.